# Trees in graph theory

Tags: graph-theory

How many distinct trees can be constructed using 3 nodes, 4 nodes , 5 nodes and 10 nodes?
i was thinking there was 3 distinct trees in 3 nodes , but am not sure about the rest.

Comment: I see only two non-homeomorphic trees on three nodes?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I am only seeing 1 - you must draw 2 edges

Comment: @gt6989b Right, I was thinking of 4 nodes.

Answer (score 1):

**HINTS**

1. If you have a tree on $n$ vertices, and remove a leaf, what do you get?
2. Can you construct all trees on $n$ vertices using trees on $n-1$ vertices?
3. Play with $n=3,4,5$ cases to see the pattern, and apply it to $n=10$...

Comment: when you remove a leaf , the vertice reduces by one and also the egde reduces by one.
And i think you can construct all trees like that.
but finding how many distinct tree there are with n nodes its quite tricky, because with smaller nodes like 2 and 3 , you can actually draw out all possible tree and take out the identical ones out , but when the number of nodes is 4, 5..., it becomes a bit difficult, is there like a formula to work it out.

Comment: @BSmith more importantly, you also get a tree.